# How do you say "if ... else" in logic notation?

Tags: logic, notation

I know that "if a then b" is represented as $a \implies b$, but how is "if a then b else c" represented?

I know in most programming languages there's a way to write this, but is there a way to write it in logic notation? Thanks in advance :]

Comment: $(a \implies b) \wedge ((\neg a) \implies c)$?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Ah, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh @ChrisEagle, by the way, is there a way you could write this as an answer instead of a comment? I hear questions answered in the comments get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you want is $(a \implies b) \wedge ((\neg a) \implies c)$.

(This was previously a comment; posting it as an answer as requested)

Comment: Quick follow-up — would we need the parenthesis around the ¬a if they were close enough that is just implied that the a was negated and not the (a => c)?

Comment: This is a matter of convention.  I think the most common convention is that $\neg$ has priority over any of the binary connectives, so that $\neg a \implies c$ should be read as $(\neg a) \implies c$ anyway, but I also think that it is just clearer to put the parentheses in and leave nothing to chance.